# Interpolating a closed curve using scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, curve-fitting

I'm writing a python script to interpolate a given set of points with splines. The points are defined by their `[x, y]` coordinates.

I tried to use this code:

```
x = np.array([23, 24, 24, 25, 25])
y = np.array([13, 12, 13, 12, 13])
tck, u = scipy.interpolate.splprep([x,y], s=0)
unew = np.arange(0, 1.00, 0.005)
out = scipy.interpolate.splev(unew, tck)
```

which gives me a curve like this:

[image: Bad Interpolation]

However, I need to have a smooth closed curve - on the picture above the derivatives at one of the points are obviously not the same.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: quite a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739006/how-to-smooth-this-data/33746521#33746521

Comment: @lejlot You're right, but this one is a much better question

Comment: problem is the same, answer is the same, it does not really matter what is "cool" ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your closed path can be considered as a parametric curve, *x=f(u)*, *y=g(u)* where *u* is distance along the curve, bounded on the interval *[0, 1)*. You can use [`scipy.interpolate.splprep`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splprep.html#scipy.interpolate.splprep) with `per=True` to treat your `x` and `y` points as periodic, then evaluate the fitted splines using [`scipy.interpolate.splev`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splev.html#scipy.interpolate.splev):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.array([23, 24, 24, 25, 25])
y = np.array([13, 12, 13, 12, 13])

# append the starting x,y coordinates
x = np.r_[x, x[0]]
y = np.r_[y, y[0]]

# fit splines to x=f(u) and y=g(u), treating both as periodic. also note that s=0
# is needed in order to force the spline fit to pass through all the input points.
tck, u = interpolate.splprep([x, y], s=0, per=True)

# evaluate the spline fits for 1000 evenly spaced distance values
xi, yi = interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0, 1, 1000), tck)

# plot the result
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(x, y, 'or')
ax.plot(xi, yi, '-b')
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfect if I don't append the starting coordinates.

Comment: Really? Doesn't work for me - I get a 'figure of 8' if I don't append the starting coordinates. The docs for the `per` argument also say *"If non-zero, data points are considered periodic with period x[m-1] - x[0] and a smooth periodic spline approximation is returned. Values of y[m-1] and w[m-1] are not used."*, which suggests to me that it will ignore the last coordinates in `x` and `y`.

Comment: I get this problem if I append coordinates: https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2007-September/013650.html

Comment: Weird. Maybe it's version-related? All I can say is that appending the start coordinates works perfectly for me using scipy 0.14.1 and 0.16.0, whereas not appending them results in a figure-of-eight curve that does not pass through the point at (25, 13). Perhaps it has something to do with the extra point in your plot at (22, 13)?

Comment: @ali_m would it be possible to evaluate the spline fits for `n` specific values (instead of 1000 evenly spaced distance values)?