# Interpolate from periodic closed curve data in R

Tags: r

Let us consider few points from a closed curve `f(x): [0,2*pi] -> (0, +Inf)`, as follows

```
x <- c(0.0000000, 0.6283185, 1.2566371, 1.8849556, 2.5132741, 
3.1415927,3.7699112, 4.3982297, 5.0265482, 5.6548668, 6.2769021)
```

and

```
f <- c(7.156246, 2.634750, 4.012373, 5.734145, 6.812517,
6.072547,5.821391, 6.331051,4.900359, 5.825402, 7.176812)
```

Then how to interpolate values of the function f at some given points `(2.3,10)` in R?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962717/interpolating-a-closed-curve-using-scipy) people have done similar work using `scipy` function of Python. How to do it in R?

Comment: R Documentation: http://www.astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/stats/html/approxfun.html

Comment: @Marichyasana. Thank you. It serves the purpose.