# Interpolate polar/circular data with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a sparse data set, `f44`, made up of bearings in degrees and ssi (dbm) values:

```
       ssi
deg       
4.0    -69
59.0   -73
162.0  -73
267.0  -61
319.0  -75
```

I reindexed `f44` to include all the missing indices from 0-359:

```
f44i = f44.reindex(np.arange(0,360))
```

When I interpolate (using quadratic) and plot the figure, it's apparent that the result doesn't interpolate between the first/lowest bearing and the highest:

```
f44i = f44i.interpolate(method='quadratic')
f44i.plot()
```

[image: naive interpolation]

**How can I interpolate this data in a way that will fill in between 0 and 360 degrees?** The [`pandas Series.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html#pandas.Series.interpolate) documentation does not appear to have anything built-in, nor does the [`scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#univariate-interpolation) documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not convinced this is the best way to do this, but it seems to work. Please add something if there is a better way.

Since I'm only interested in 0-360 degrees, I can duplicate the dataset from -360-0, and 360-720, expanding my original data set to the left and right, like so:

```
import numpy as  np    

# Create left side
f44il = f44i.copy()
f44il.index = np.arange(-360,0)

# Create right side
f44ir = f44i.copy()
f44ir.index = np.arange(360,720)
```

Interpolating and plotting the result looks promising (the third command shows 0-360 in a different color):

```
f44expanded = pd.concat([f44il, f44i, f44ir]).interpolate(method='quadratic')
f44expanded.plot()
f44expanded[np.arange(0,360)].plot()
```

[image: repeating data]

Then I can just create a new series from the interpolated data with an index from 0-360, which looks like it gives me exactly what I want:

```
f44final = f44expanded[np.arange(0,360)]
f44final.plot()
```

[image: final plot]

I suspect there is a better way to do this, so feel free to add an answer if you know of one.

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternative approach to this problem using `scipy` to interpolate onto a closed curve. First, I converted your data from (deg, ssi) to *psuedo* cartesian coordinates (x,y) assuming `deg` is the polar angle and `ssi` is the (negative) of the radial distance. Then you can use the method defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33962986/8936101) to interpolate a closed curve onto a set of (x,y) points.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

dic = {'deg': [4.0, 59.0, 162.0, 267.0, 319.0],
       'ssi': [-69, -73, -73, -61, -75]}

f44  = pandas.DataFrame(data=dic)

'''
Now, lets do the following. Convert your data from (deg, ssi) to (x,y)
where x = ssi* cosd(deg), y=ssi*sind(deg). Now we need to interpolate a closed
curve onto these set of cartesian points.  
'''

f44['x'] = -f44['ssi']*np.cos( np.deg2rad(f44['deg']))
f44['y'] = -f44['ssi']*np.sin( np.deg2rad(f44['deg']))

x = f44.as_matrix(columns=[f44.columns[2]])[:,0]
y = f44.as_matrix(columns=[f44.columns[3]])[:,0]
x = np.r_[x, x[0]]
y = np.r_[y, y[0]]

tck, u = interpolate.splprep([x, y], s=0, per=True)
xi, yi = interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0, 1, 1000), tck)

# Save interpolated data to new dataframe. 
f44i = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'x':xi, 'y':yi})

f44i['deg'] = np.rad2deg( np.arctan2(f44i['y'],f44i['x']))
f44i['ssi'] =-np.sqrt( f44i['x']**2 + f44i['y']**2)

for i,l in enumerate(f44i['deg']):
    if l < 0:
        f44i['deg'][i] = 360 + f44i['deg'][i]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(f44i['deg'], f44i['ssi'], '.', markersize=0.5)
ax.plot(f44['deg'], f44['ssi'], '.', color='red')
plt.show()
```

Now we get a curve that looks like the one below. (re-converted from the psuedo cartesian coordinates to your preferred (deg, ssi) coordinates). Also, I have created a new dataframe to replace the `f44i` you created. You can make this code more suitable for your specific application.

[image: Interpolation using a closed curve.]

Comment: That's a great approach, thank you. I like the output from mine better, the second peak in yours doesn't make much sense to me since there is no value that really justifies that peak. I'll see if I can dissect your answer and apply a better interpolation function.

Comment: Thank you. You're right that trying to fit a spline with less points leads to oscillations (see [Runge's Phenomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon)). The interpolation will get better with a larger number of points. You can also try playing with different smoothing parameters and degree for the B-spline to get a better curve (`s=0` enforces that the interpolated curve passes through all points).